# Adding a exclusion to a query. Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a exclusion to a query.

There are 4 tables:

- Published_books
- Parameters_values
- Shipments
- Orders

Right now in the first query I'm asking Publications with column (plaza_type) with the parameter value of "best"

But, I want too, exclude from the first query: the bought publications (the second query). But bought publications are when a shipment (table) are create and an Orders (table)  are created too and with a status of "valid", "partial", "sent", "received".

I have two arrays:

```
        $eliteBooks = BookPublication::join('parameter_values', 'published_books.plaza_type', '=', 'parameter_values.id')
    ->select('published_books.*')
    ->where(function($query) use($then, $now)
    {
        $query->whereBetween('published_books.created_at', [$then, $now])
              ->where('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'best');
    })
    ->orderBy('published_books.created_at', 'desc')->take(12)
    ->get()->chunk(6)->map(function($value)
    {
        return $value->chunk(3);
    });
```

And the second one

```
    $recentBoughtExchanged = BookPublication::join('shipments', 'published_books.id', '=', 'shipments.published_book_id')
    ->join('orders', 'shipments.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->join('parameter_values', 'orders.order_status', '=', 'parameter_values.id')
    ->select('published_books.*')
    ->where(function($query) use($then, $now)
    {
        $query->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [$then, $now])
              ->where('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'valid')
              ->orWhere('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'partial')
              ->orWhere('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'sent')
              ->orWhere('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'received');
    })
    ->groupBy('published_books.id')
    ->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()->chunk(6)->map(function($value)
    {
        return $value->chunk(3);
    });
```

Any help? I want to exclude the results from the second one in the first one, in order to show just publications that CAN be bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutionated adding a `filter` in the query:

```
   $eliteBooks = BookPublication::join('parameter_values', 'published_books.plaza_type', '=', 'parameter_values.id')
    ->select('published_books.*')
    ->where(function($query) use($then, $now)
    {
        $query->whereBetween('published_books.created_at', [$then, $now])
              ->where('parameter_values.pvalue', '=', 'best');           
    })
    ->orderBy('published_books.created_at', 'desc')->take(12)
    ->get()->filter(function($publication) {
        return $publication->can_be_bought;
    })->chunk(6)->map(function($value)
    {
        return $value->chunk(3);
    });
```

$publication is defined in the model BookPublication, and **can_be_bought** in a method defined too.